# two column article templates

Tags: two-column, templates, article

I have been looking on `tex.stackexchange` and Googling but I can't find a decent two column template.

Does anyone know of site or have a template for a two column article style tex file?

That has a bibliography portion as well?

Comment: What do you consider "decent"?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina something along geared for scientific journals

Comment: The IEEE has the `IEEEtran` document class. You can see a sample document in the [IEEEtran_HOWTO](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf) document. Some scientific journals provide their own tailored templates.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina how to add the file to texlive?  I tried adding the resume class to texlive and recompiling mktexslr or whatever it is called but texlive still couldn't load the resume class saying it isn't installed.

Comment: `IEEEtran` ships with TeX Live. Do you have the package manager `tlmgr`? If you need a manual installation, Stefan's answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/3954 can help you with the precess.

Comment: (If I remember correctly, you use Ubuntu.) You can easily add a class to your personal tree.  Copy/move, say, `res.cls` to `~/texmf/tex/latex/res/` (you can create this folder with `mkdir -p ~/texmf/tex/latex/res`). As soon as you move it there, you should be able to find it with: `kpsewhich res.cls`, even without running `mktexslr`.  If it can't be found, you have an unusual problem with your system, and should ask for help.

Comment: @jon so in terminal I just type `kpsewhich res.cls`?

Comment: Once it has been copied to where I suggested, `kpsewhich res.cs` should return `/home/<dustin>/texmf/tex/latex/res/res.cls` (assuming you are logged in as 'dustin'). If it does, that means the class file should be as usable as any other regular class file.

Comment: @jon I shouldn't put it in `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf`?

Comment: No.  If you put it there, you still want to follow the TDS structure and put it in `/usr/local/.../texmf/tex/latex/res/` (best make the directory too while you're at it) as it is a **LaTeX** thing.  But what is the advantage?  It is easier to access and keep track of your local `texmf`, and there is less danger of manually installed classes and style files getting overwritten by system updates (which is probably not a serious concern, but still).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In [www.latextemplates.com](http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/articles) there are 3 nice general LaTeX templates for articles. One of these made with the `scrartcl` class have this layout:

[image: Article template]

Another good source  is [www.sharelatex.com](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/). Among the **76** articles templates for submission to scientific journals or proceedings, several have a two column format. You can download or open and compile in ShareLaTeX.

In any case, as most code of article templates are interchangeable between the standard `article` class and others general article class (as `paper`, `scrartcl`, `artikel`, etc.) as well as in specific journal class (as `svjour3`, etc.) you can experiment easily with most classes with the same template replacing the first line (that is, change `\docummentclass{article}` by `\docummentclass{paper}` but search in each case in the documentation for specific options to add/remove for each class (for example, `paper` class have a `\smalltableofcontents` that you cannot use in the `article` class, but `\tableofcontents` work in any class).

Answer (score 12):

I'm new to LaTeX and I've spent a few days searching for two-column article templates and tried out the ones mentioned in the main answer and a dozen others. I hit various issues and finally landed on this clean and simple template that I think also answers this question (which is the top tex stackexchange search result for "two column") and many newbies like me will find useful (screenshot below):

```
% test.tex
\title{Article Title\cite{LinkReference1}}

\author{Some Author\cite{Author1}}

\newcommand{\abstractText}{\noindent
Abstract goes here.
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Configuration %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[super,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{abstract}
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\small\itshape}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% References %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% If changing the name of the bib file, change \bibliography{test} at the bottom
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}

@misc{LinkReference1,
  title        = "Link Title",
  author       = "Link Creator(s)",
  howpublished = "\url{https://example.com/}",
}

@misc{Author1,
  author       = "LastName, FirstName",
  howpublished = "\url{mailto:email@example.com}",
}

@article{ArticleReference1,
  author  = "Lastname1, Firstname1 and Lastname2, Firstname2",
  title   = "Article title",
  year    = "Year",
  journal = "Journal name",
  note    = "\url{https://dx.doi.org/...}",
}

\end{filecontents}

% Any configuration that should be done before the end of the preamble:
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Abstract %
%%%%%%%%%%%%

\twocolumn[
  \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
      \abstractText
      \newline
      \newline
    \end{abstract}
  \end{@twocolumnfalse}
]

%%%%%%%%%%%
% Article %
%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{Section1Title}

This is the first sentence\cite{ArticleReference1}.

\section{Section2Title}

\lipsum[1]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% References %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}

% Create PDF on Linux:
% FILE=test; pkill -9 -f ${FILE} &>/dev/null; rm -f ${FILE}*aux ${FILE}*bbl ${FILE}*bib ${FILE}*blg ${FILE}*log ${FILE}*out ${FILE}*pdf &>/dev/null; pdflatex -halt-on-error ${FILE}; bibtex ${FILE} && pdflatex ${FILE} && pdflatex ${FILE} && (xdg-open ${FILE}.pdf &)
```

Screenshot:

[image: Example screenshot]

As noted in detail in the last line of the file, to process the inline bib file, the general procedure is to run pdflatex multiple times and bibtex after the first run. For example:

```
$ pdflatex -halt-on-error test
$ bibtex test
$ pdflatex test.tex
$ pdflatex test.tex
# Now open test.pdf
```

To reduce the margins:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=1cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,includehead,includefoot}
\setlength{\columnsep}{7mm} % Column separation width
```

Comment: You are loading hyperref too early.

Comment: @Johannes_B Interesting, can you explain more why that's an issue and how to fix it?

Comment: Load the package at the end of the preamble. There are only a few exceptions, `hyperref` should be loaded last.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks, so just to confirm, you're saying that `\usepackage{hyperref}` and `\hypersetup[...]` should always be loaded right before `\begin{document}`?

Comment: Not always. But there are only very few exceptions.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks, I've updated my answer. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for have cerate this :)

Comment: This is incredibly helpful, I can't believe how hard it is to find something similar on Google. Just one thing for my lightweight tex installation: `tlmgr install lipsum`, `tlmgr install abstract`

Comment: Thanks, for sharing. This worked as presented.