# Convert two column tex document to html

Tags: tex4ht, html

I want to produce a html output for a basic two column article given in [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/468659/95518). I used `htlatex` to produce the html output. However the output is in single column format.

> Is there any way to produce two column html output from .tex input?

[image]

Comment: I am afraid that this is your work to decide where each DIV column tag should start or end. There are no pages in HTML, and therefore it is not possible to guess where an automatic column break should be.  You can export the format of a  table with two columns, but not the format of a two column document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. I am aware of the CSS potential at this respect,  but I mean that is not possible to guess what kind of columns the user want for a page without real dimensions. Even assuming that the user just want to reproduce the PDF column breaks,  I suppose that will be a nightmare to implement an exporting tool doing this  when the columns/page breaks could be explicit in the text and/or  implicit in the LaTeX preamble in so many ways.

Answer (score 1):

Two-column output doesn't really make sense for HTML output where the presentation is more of a continuous scroll than a page-based output. That said, if you *really* want two columns, this can be managed using CSS with the `column-count` property.

You'll need to wrap the body of the article in an environment so that it can be enclosed in a `div` tag in the HTML output. See [tex4ht: Wrapping several paragraphs inside a div tag](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/490921/tex4ht-wrapping-several-paragraphs-inside-a-div-tag) for details on this. Then you can either modify the example at that link to explicitly have `style="column-count:2"` or do it through a CSS style sheet.

But again, you really do *not* want to do this.